# Recreate "Desktop" directory

Tags: desktop-environments

I accidentally deleted `~/Desktop`. This directory plays some kind of important role because now that it is gone all of the folders under `~/` are showing up on my accounts desktop. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to go to a terminal and type:

```
mkdir ~/Desktop
```

and then press <kbd>F5</kbd> on the desktop to refresh it.

Answer (score 2):

First you should create the directory again:

```
mkdir ~/Desktop
```

Now if the default icon has not appear then you should edit `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file.

```
gedit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

It should be same as this:

```
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Take a look over [this](http://blog.e-shell.org/237) for more information

**NB:** you may need to have a restart or logout and then login to apply the new settings